# How to compare facts from multiple host inside ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

How do I create a playbook that compare the facts of multiple host in Ansible? I would like to be able to compare hosts against one another to discover one-offs. All my workstations should be the exact same.

```
- name: Gather Facts
  hosts: all
  - debug: var=vars
  - debug: vars=hostvars[inventory_hostname]
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname] | difference([inventory_hostname]) }}""
```

Comment: do you want to compare all facts between all hosts?

Comment: Yes. I would like to find the difference between the hosts.